# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre de la ciudad donde está un marcador (Google Maps y C# WinForms)?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, google-maps

me gustaría saber como obtengo el nombre de una ciudad donde he puesto el marcador, lo que tengo capturado es la longitud y latitud...

Ésta es la función que me captura la latitud y longitud

```
private void gMapControl_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    lat = gMapControl.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y).Lat;
    lng = gMapControl.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y).Lng;

    //posicionar el marcador
    marker.Position = new PointLatLng(lat, lng);
    //En este punto quisiera tomar el nombre de la ciudad para guardarlo en un txt
    marker.ToolTipText = string.Format("Ciudad: \n{0}", txtCiudad.Text);
}
```

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque sin código, es difícil ayudarte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2875/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes recuperar el `place` y trabajar con sus propiedades.

```
double lat = gMapControl.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y).Lat;
double lng = gMapControl.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y).Lng;


List<Placemark> plc = null;
var st = GMapProviders.GoogleMap.GetPlacemarks(map.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y), out plc);
if (st == GeoCoderStatusCode.G_GEO_SUCCESS && plc != null)
{
    foreach (var pl in plc)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pl.PostalCodeNumber))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Accuracy: " + pl.Accuracy + ", " + pl.Address + ", PostalCodeNumber: " + pl.PostalCodeNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: recuerda hacer `using GMap.NET.MapProviders;` y referenciar `GMap.NET.Core.dll`

Comment: Muchas gracias, pude obtener el nombre de la localidad gracias a tu ayuda!

Comment: donde se origina el map? noo se donde proviene

Answer (score 0):

No indicas a que hace referencia map.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y). He probado con el control de mi mapa y tampoco funciona. Deduzco que en e.X y e.Y son las coordenadas, pero no va a funcionar si no se sabe a que hacer referencia el map

Edito:

Después de realizar varias pruebas y buscar soluciones por fin puedo decirte cual es el problema.

Primero he de indicarte que gMap.Net solo ofrece de forma gratuita los servicios básicos, si deseas obtener otros datos como dirección, empresas, etc debes utilizar la API de Google.

Para añadir la API en C#:

```
GMapProviders.GoogleMap.ApiKey = @"Aquí su API google";
```

Si no tienes la API deberás conseguir una, y por desgracia ya no es gratis para el primer año.

Le adjunto el código que me ha funcionado:

```
PointLatLng pointLatLng = new PointLatLng(latitud, longitud);

List<Placemark> placemarks = new List<Placemark>();
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
var st = GMapProviders.GoogleMap.GetPlacemarks(gMapControl1.FromLocalToLatLng(41, 2), out placemarks);
{
                        foreach (var pl in placemarks)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pl.PostalCodeNumber))
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine("Accuracy: " + pl.Accuracy + ", " + pl.Address + ", PostalCodeNumber: " + pl.PostalCodeNumber);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/351752)